# Renaming items in a File::Find folder traversal

Tags: perl, recursion, tree

I am supposed to traverse through a whole tree of folders and rename everything (including folders) to lower case. I looked around quite a bit and saw that the best way was to use [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind).  I tested this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use File::Find;
use strict;

print "Folder: ";
chomp(my $dir = <STDIN>);

find(\&lowerCase, $dir);

sub lowerCase{
    print $_," = ",lc($_),"\n";
    rename $_, lc($_);
}
```

and it seems to work fine. But can anyone tell me if I might run into trouble with this code?  I remember posts on how I might run into trouble because of renaming folders before files or something like that.

Comment: If the lowercase version already exists, you will overwrite it.

Comment: @jordanm - Good call.  Perhaps `rename $_, lc($_) unless -e $_`

Comment: That should be `rename $_, lc($_) unless -e lc($_);`

Comment: hmm...yea, tried it both ways, and either way it wont rename unless i take out the unless -e portion.

Comment: Not sure how File::Find works internally, but a possible complication might be that you change the list of files while iterating through it.

Comment: @imakeitrayne Are you using windows? I seem to have the same case insensitive `-e` function.

Comment: @imakeitrayne I am not sure that windows can distinguish between different case. But on the other hand, then you can most likely skip the test.

Comment: well, i figured i might as well test for that just in case, so i simply used an if statement "if($_ ne lc($_))" to test if the lc version already exists...

Comment: On Windows there can be no two files with the same name apart from case differences. The test is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are **on Windows**, as comments stated, then no, renaming files or folders in any order won't be a problem, because a path `DIR1/file1` is the same as `dir1/file1` to Windows.

   It MAY be a problem on Unix though, in which case you are better off doing a recursive BFS by hand.
2. Also, when doing system calls like rename, ALWAYS check result:

   ```
    rename($from, $to) || die "Error renaming $from to $to: $!";
   ```
3. As noted in comments, take care about renaming "ABC" to "abc". On Windows is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for help, I ran it on a linux server and indeed I came across a problem where the program could not find the root folder because the folder name had already been change...but I read some more and found that "finddepth(\&wanted,  @directories);" does the same job in postorder traversal instead of preorder, which solved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to:

1. List files to be renamed using `find dir/ > 2b_renamed`
2. Review the list manually, using an editor of choice (`vim 2b_renamed`, in my case)
3. Use the [rename from CPAN](https://metacpan.org/module/rename) on that list: `xargs rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' < 2b_renamed`

That *manual review* is very important to me, even when I can easily rollback changes (via git or even Time Machine).